# Hot to call to ASP.NET file from VBS file?

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

How can I call to a ASP.NET file (.aspx) from a VBS file that are both on the SAME server ?

I need that the VBS file will execute the asp.net file with some parameters.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
Dim ie
Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.app  location")
ie.Navigate "http://www.mysite.com/mypage.aspx?q=1"
ie.Visible=True
```

or

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run "iexplore http://www.mysite.com/mypage.aspx?q=1", 9 
WScript.Sleep 10000 ' Give ie some time to load

'Close the browser 
WshShell.SendKeys "%F" 
WshShell.SendKeys "C"
```

or

rebember that you run web pages directly from the **Task Scheduler** and use **[curl](http://curl.haxx.se/)**

Comment: Is there a way to do it without starting the explorer? remember that both files (vbs and aspx) are on the same machine.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ServerXMLHttp:-

```
 dim xhr : set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp.3.0")
 xhr.open "GET", "http://yoursite/youcode.ashx?params=x", false
 xhr.send
 if xht.status = 200 then
    msgbox "Success :)"
 else
    msgbox "Failed :("
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in your .vbs file

```
Set winHttpRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
winHttpRequest.Open "GET", "http://localhost/mypage.aspx", false

winHttpRequest.Send

WScript.Echo(winHttpRequest.GetAllResponseHeaders())
WScript.Echo(winHttpRequest.ResponseText)
```

For more examples, see http://www.neilstuff.com/winhttp/

You should be able to call any URL (including .aspx pages) on your server (or on the internet)